# HTML startapp view inside Graphics.element.container

Tags: elm

I am trying to place my html view in the middle of a container.

Unfortunately, container gives output of type `Graphics.Element.Element` whereas html view must be of the type, `Html.Html`.

And also, the html element constructors like `div, checkbox, button, body` return type is `Html` whereas, container needs a `Graphics.Element` parameter.

This is an erroneous html view, which i would like to make it work,

```
view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Element
view address model =
  container 1000 1000 middle <|
    toForm <|
      div []
        [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [text "-"]
        , div [ countStyle ] [ text (toString model ) ]
        , button [ onClick address Increment ] [ text "+" ] 
        ]
```

It has `two buttons`, `one div` all placed in the middle of a 1000 * 1000 container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elm-html package has a [`fromElement`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.1/Html#fromElement) that can be used to create an `Html` from an `Element`.

I will say though, the idea with elm-html is to allow for a more "normal" flow of rendering HTML and using CSS to style it. While it would *work* to take your `Html`, convert it to an to either a `Form` or `Element`, use a collage or container to move it to the center of some area, and then convert back to Html, I'd probably recommend against it. If you're using HTML, just render that and style it (either with an external stylesheet or with[`Html.Attributes`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.1/Html-Attributes#style)).